# $p$-polynomial of $n$'th degree, $q(x)=p[x,x_1,x_2,...,x_k]$, prove that q has the same leading coefficient.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation

So I have a polynomial $p$ of $n$'th degree and q given by $q(x)=p[x,x_1,x_2,...,x_k]$, meaning that for $x$ it gives back the leading coefficient in interpolation of $p$ on points $x,x_1,...,x_k$. Prove that q is of degree $n-k$, and the coefficient beside $x^{n-k}$ is the same, as the one beside $x^n$ in $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question, a counterexample.  $f(x)=x^2$ interpolated at two points is linear, $Ax+B$, and $A$ is dependent on the two points, not only the coefficient of $x^2$ in $f$.

The statement in the new question is correct, because if you allow the interpolation points to include $x$, and substitute $x$ into the result, you recover the original polynomial completely, not only its highest degree term, and
$c(x) \prod (x -x_i)$ is the unique part of this expression with highest degree of $x$.

Comment: The theorem is not true, isn't it? If I interpolate $x^2$ on $1,2$ I will get $3x-2$, and $1$ is equal to $3$...

Comment: Yes, the example was to demonstrate that the statement is false.

Comment: Thanks, I will mail my lecturer that he made a mistake in the exercises :)

Comment: What if I define $q$ as $q(x)=[x,x_1,...,x_k]$? The statement is still false, right? Since $q(1)=x^2[1,2]=3x-2$...

Comment: $[x,...x_n]$ applied to what function?

Comment: I'm so sorry, but I think I must've messed up the exercise.$q$ is the polynomial given by $q(x)=p[x,x_1,...,x_k]$. Meaning that it's that for $x$ is gives back the leading coefficient in the newton polynomial for points $x,x_1,...,x_k$, and not that it is a newton polynomial.

Comment: I updated the answer, but if you modify questions on SE, keep the earlier versions visible so that the answers do not become meaningless.

Comment: I'm sorry for troubling you, I'm extremely grateful for all your help so far, but could you be more elaborate in your explanation? What do you mean by 'because if you allow the interpolation points to include x, and substitute x into the result,'? I know that $q(x)$ equals $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m} \frac{f(x_k)}{\prod\limits_{j=0,j\neq k}^{m}(x_k-x_j)}$, where $x_0=x$, and I just don't see how that makes it a polynomial...

Comment: For interpolation points $x_0, \dots x_k$ the interpolant is a sum of polynomials $p_i = c_i(X-x_0)\dots(X-x_{k-1})$ of degrees $0,1,2,...k$. The coefficient $c_i$ is a polynomial in $(x_k, x_{k-1}, \dots, x_0)$.  My claim is that if you evaluate the interpolant on $(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_{k-1},x)$ you get the original polynomial.

Comment: Meaning that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^m \frac{f(x_k)}{\prod\limits_{j=0,j\neq k}^m}(x_k-x_j) \prod\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}(x-x_i)$ equals $p$? But aren't they supposed to have different degrees by my theorem?

Comment: No, because $c_k(x)$ has degree $n-k$ in $x_k$ and degree $k$ in $x$, and we substitute $x$ for $x_k$.  So degree $n$ for both, at least potentially.